# Wifi dropping every 20 mins

Tags: wireless, lenovo

My wifi keeps dropping every 20 minutes or so (on my home network), and will not let me connect again until I reboot my laptop. This is not a network problem, as wifi is stable on my cell phone. Could this be a ubuntu problem, or a hardware problem? I am running a lenovo x220.

Related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/346529/ubuntu-keeps-disconnecting-from-wifi

Output from sudo lspci -nnk | grep -B4 Network:

```
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:21da]
    Kernel driver in use: mei
    Kernel modules: mei
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
--
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:21da]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
```

Comment: What adapter are you using?

Comment: Doing sudo lspci -v tells me I have an Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 network controller. The Eternet Controller is an Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection. @Braiam

Comment: Could you edit your question? add the output of `sudo lspci -nnk | grep -B4 Network`

Comment: Sure, I just edited it with that output

Comment: I have very similar problem still fighting with it.

[enter link description here][1] 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/492356/wireless-wi-fi-not-connecting-sometimes-especially-first-time

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, nothing worked with my Netgear USB. The connection dropped every five minutes and had to be reactivated.

The following solve the problem. My connection is now stable and working great.

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with my wife's Sony VAIO. It was a bad wireless adapter. I replaced it, and have had no more problems. Been a few months now. It was an Atheros AR9285 if I recall. Many laptops use the Atheros adapters.

Comment: Doing sudo lspci -v tells me I have an Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 network controller

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on my Lenovo laptop.
It could be most likely a driver error.

Try using `sudo lshw | grep network` to check your driver's name.
Then use `dmesg | grep <your_driver_name>` and see if there are any error logs related to it.

If you find errors, go here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported and see if the driver ubuntu detected on is the one you need.

In my case it turned out that ubuntu forced some newer driver on my wifi card. If this is also your problem, then you'll need to change the module, but I'm still trying to figure that out.

Comment: Hmm, no bugs showing up for me, but thanks for the troubleshooting tip.

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was going to Edit Connections, choosing the particular connection, going to the IPV6 tab, and setting it to "Ignore".

Ubuntu has issues with their IPV6 on some systems.   Mine worked great for 5 years.  Then a after a routine update, it would drop consistently every 20 minutes.    Disabled the IPV6, and back in business.

Comment: ***DO NOT*** repost the same answer to many many different questions.  Instead, if the questions are similar enough that the answers also answer the question, flag the questions as duplicates.

Comment: I'm new on here and not exactly sure how to even do that, but wouldn't it be more efficient for moderators to link those common questions together then chase after the answers to them?    Or better yet, when there's hundreds of the same question, such as in this case, report a bug?